# passing activity/fragment reference to Databinded layout in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I have a simple example of an app using MVVM and databinding, which is basically two EditTexts, and then a button.
a click on the button should open a new activity.

Is there any reason not to pass activity reference to the layout, and then call it to invoke a new activity ?

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="firstActivity"
        type="com.example.view.FirstActivity"/>

</data>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="@{() -> firstActivity.navigateToNextPage()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

its complete violation of MVVM architecture as you always bind your view model to your layout not your view.

view should be independent so to attain loose coupling for example in this scenario the intent code is in View which is directly ivoked by the layout without viewmodel intervene .

As the view knows on what basis you are going to new activity ,so the business logic is in the view which is not a regular approach what a developers do .

Wait...... I thinks a utter a lot above so what will be the solution?? Look beloww

1.Create a view Model of a respective View 
2. Bind your editText also as you bind your button ,hey but wait with your viewModel this time.

3. write your business logic in your viewmodel .

4.bind that logic function in OnClicked of your layout .

5. Now write an on property change event in viewmodel.
6. Call that onproperty change event by using on property change call back .
7. you are done then only u can hit your Intent function.

So at last View does not know anything why its going to the different actiivty .

Note:-

Newbie in stack overflow ,so pardon for breaking any violation for writing answer.
Thanks

Comment: but in this case the ViewModel doesn't do anything other than just pass the same function to the activity.
It will be like:
in layout : viewmodel.nextPage();
in viewmodel : presenter.nextPage();

Comment: its not passing any fun to activity , activity just get notified through property changed variable , when the logic part is done in the viewmodel , and then activity will do its part without knowing why its doing, thus attain abstraction.

Comment: the thing is, there is no logic in the viewmodel in this specific case. It's only a click on a button that opens a new activity straight away. Seems a bit "exaggerated" to run this simple task through a pipline of layout-->viewmodel-->activity. no ?

Comment: yeah but that normally not happens right , this you are doing may be for learning purpose but in real world case where you ll find huge no of activtites and fragments,

Comment: there MVVM come into picture to make things more readable and testable and to attain loose coupling, i hope i make sense to you